# Firestore: Failed to get documents from server

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

While trying to read documents from Firestore, I occasionally get the following error when using `get(GetOptions(source: Source.server))`

I have the following code

```
QuerySnapshot items = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup(collectionId).where("id", isEqualTo: id).get(GetOptions(source: Source.server));
```

which works fine most of the time for a given 'id' but sometimes, for the same 'id', it fails with

```
[cloud_firestore/unavailable] Failed to get documents from server. 
(However, these documents may exist in the local cache. 
Run again without setting source to "server" to retrieve the cached documents.)
```

Does this error imply that there was a bad network connection? Or are there other conditions that can trigger this error?

Comment: Does the doc exist on the firebase end? I know it is not great question to ask but if it happens, can you check?

Comment: the doc indeed exists

Comment: Insufficient details provided. please add more details and your code also

Comment: added the code fragment and some more details.  Basically, I want to know what I can conclude from the given error: can I conclude that there was a network issue? or are there other possible explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `[cloud_firestore/unavailable] Failed to get documents from server` implies that either there was a network issue or the Firestore server was unreachable for some reason when you tried fetching the documents with `source: Source.server.`

When you do `source: Source.server`, it means: Try to get the documents from the server. An error will be thrown if the server is unreachable due to issues like server downtime, network issue etc.

Ideally, you could perform the operation in a try catch. Try fetching with `source: Source.server`, catch the exception and check the exception code. Where the code is unavailable, try to fetch from cache by doing: `source: Source.cache`.

```
QuerySnapshot items;

try {
  items = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collectionGroup(collectionId)
      .where("id", isEqualTo: id)
      .get(GetOptions(source: Source.server));
} catch (e) {
  if (e is FirebaseFirestoreException && e.code == 'unavailable') {
    items = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup(collectionId)
        .where("id", isEqualTo: id)
        .get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
  } else {
    rethrow;
  }
}
```

For firebase exception codes, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the error codes!